# Hide div with all content in this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to hide div with all content in div
this is my  code :

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
<p for="name">text :</p><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name_g; ?>" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)"/>
<p for="phone">text :</p><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone_g; ?>" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)"/>
<p for="blood">text :</p><input type="text" name="blood" value="<?php echo $blood_g; ?>" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)"/>
<p for="id">text :</p><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id2_g; ?>" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)"/>
<p for="email">text : </p><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email_g; ?>" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)"/>
<input type="button" onclick =" printvalues();" value="text"> 

<div id="info_check">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printvalues() {
        var div = document.getElementById("info_check");
        div.innerHTML += "<span>text :</span>"+form.name.value+"<br>";
        div.innerHTML += "<span>text :</span>"+form.phone.value+"<br>";
        div.innerHTML += "<span>text :</span>"+form.blood.value+"<br>";
        div.innerHTML += "<span>text :</span>"+form.id.value+"<br>";
        div.innerHTML += "<span>text :</span>"+form.email.value+"<br>";
        div.innerHTML += "<input type='submit' name='sub' value='text'/>";
        $("#info_check").show();
    }
</script>
<h2>text</h2>
<input type='button' onclick="$('#info_check').hide();" value='text' style='background: #F00 none repeat scroll 0% 0%; min-width: 20px; width: 80px;color: #fff; border-radius:4px; text-decoration: none; margin-right: 10px;'/>
</div>
</form>
```

my problem is i want to hode #info_check with all content in this

Comment: And what is the issue???Error in console?

Comment: Two things, we don't know what is `#info_check` element (no HTML markup provided) and we don't know how do you call `printvalues()`. You have to provide sample code to replicate issue in question itself

Answer (score 0):

As per my understnding, you want to show the preview of the form user has filled.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div id="info_check"></div>
    </form>
    <input type='button' onclick="$('#info_check').hide();" value='Hide The Div'/>
    <input type='button' onclick="$('#info_check').show();" value='Show The Div'/>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function printvalues()
        {
            var div=document.getElementById("info_check");
            div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";
            div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";
            div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";
            div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";
            div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";
            div.innerHTML+="<input type='submit' name='sub' value='Submit'/>";
        }
        printvalues();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look i print data with this button 
<input type="button" onclick =" printvalues();" value="edit"> 
if i click button data print good  but if i click again data not takes place the first data but its print below data
i want if click button change data not write again
sorry for my bad english

Comment: `div.innerHTML = "";` to reset its content. So: `var div=document.getElementById("info_check");div.innerHTML = "";div.innerHTML+="<span>text :</span>some values<br>";/*etc...*/`  But i don't see how is it related to your formr issue: `my problem is i want to hode #info_check with all content in this`